# Cannot iterate over Enumeration

Tags: scala

Here is an example from book Programming in Scala

```
object Color extends Enumeration {
    //val Red, Green, Blue = Value
    val Red = Value("Red")
    val Green = Value("Green")
}

for (d <- Color) print(d + " ") //Error value foreach is not a member of
                                // object xxx.Color
```

I have latest version of Scala. Is it the reason for error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should be:

```
for (d <- Color.values) print(d + " ")
```

There used to be a `foreach` method in `Enumeration`, which is why doing just `for (d <- Color)` worked. But it has been deprecated, and then removed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `foreach` in `Enumeration` class. If you want to iterate over values you should use method `values`. So, `for (d <- Color.values) print(d + " ")` will print `Red Green` as you expect.
Take a look on Enumeration class documentation http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration